# how does hashmap ensure that each hash value is assigned a unique index in the hash table

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I want to understand how hash() and indexOf() methods of HashMap assign a unique index in hash table to a hashmap. In other words, why it is not possible for multiple hash values to be mapped to the same index.

Comment: They could be mapped to the same index, but `HashMap` stores a list of values for a given index.

Comment: It's called a hash collision, and it happens all the time.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I mean if hashcode is 2 and it is mapped to index 1, why is it not possible that hashcode is 3 and it is mapped to same index 1 as for hash code 2

Comment: It may be, and it will generate a hash collision and the implementation of the map will handle it.

Comment: Two word answer to the title: it doesn't.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I think collision occurs when two keys have same hashcode. But I am talking of a case where hash codes are different but the hash buckets are same. How does the mapping of hash value to the bucket index work?

Comment: That's not right. `HashMap` uses the hash code of the key and then applies a method on this value to calculate the index. Imagine that a hash value is 9876514, how could you possibly use it as index for an array of 10 elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `HashMap`, the underlying bucket array size is set upon initialization and may be resized accordingly - the bucket index of an item (in `indexFor`) is generated by `key.hashCode() % (table.length - 1)`.

> how does hashmap ensure that each hash value is assigned a unique index in the hash table

The do not have to be unique (see below)

> why it is not possible for multiple hash values to be mapped to the same index

This is possible - more than one `Entry` (key/value pair) can be mapped to a single `bucket`. A proper hash table implementation overcomes this by having each `bucket` capable of holding more than a single `Entry`. `HashMap` in particular uses a linked list - if an item maps to an already occupied `bucket`, that item is added to the beginning of the bucket's linked list.

Comment: While it's true that Java's `HashMap` implementation uses linked lists to resolve collisions, this is not true of all hash-based dictionaries.  (Answer is still correct, considering this question is java-tagged.)  For completeness, when the collision ratio goes over a pre-set value, Java's (and most other) implementation of HashMap will expand the mapping table.

Comment: @bdares, thanks. Think my edit and your comment had a collision (was editing with a more generic description just as you were commenting on the lack thereof).

Comment: @copeg : Is it correct that one bucket refers to one index in the table and one unique hash value. ?

Comment: @user2599052, one bucket is one index in the underlying table - that bucket can contain more than a single item. Simple example: consider a table of length 5: if two keys have hash value's of 1 and 25, their indexes will be 1%4 and 25%4, or 1,1. Same index, and placed in sequence into the list of items at that index.

Comment: @copeg : your last example clarified the doubt. So we can say that a bucket holds a particular hash value if hash value is considered modulo the number of buckets ?

Comment: @user2599052, in the `HashTable` implementation the bucket is `hash code modulus (number of buckets - 1)`. I recommend diving into the source code and having a look at the specifics of the implementation for more information.